# Export SSL Certificate

Tags: webserver, ssl-certificate, sunone

Does the Admin Interface in Sun Web Server 7 support exporting SSL certificates?

If so, how? Please provide a reference.....

If not, could someone point me to the location where the certs are stored?

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't use the admin interface, the certutil command can export a PEM file with the certificate:

```
certutil -n nickname -d . -L -a -o myPEMfile
```

executed from the alias sub-directory of the Sun Webserver folder.